# Changing class and element text that are inside element a with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following html code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '#btnVisible', function(e) {
    // Logic Here
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Column1 </td>
      <td>
        <a id="btnVisible" href=""> <i id="IconEye" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Column2 </td>
      <td>
        <a id="btnVisible" href=""> <i id="IconEye" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Column3 </td>
      <td>
        <a id="btnVisible" href=""> <i id="IconEye" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I click on the element a and change the i class and text?

these elements are added dynamically, so when I click on the icon which is the class of i want to be able to change

Comment: `$(this).find('i').addClass(yourClass)` Also note Identifiers in HTML must be __unique__

Comment: Element ID's in a page must be unique by definition. Use class instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use addClass and removeClass I would recommend not to use Id, instead use a class selector id's are meant to identify one object...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.btnVisible', function(e) {
    // Logic Here
    $(this).find('i').addClass('my-new-class').removeClass('fa');
    return false;
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> Column1 </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btnVisible" href=""> <i id="IconEye" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Column2 </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btnVisible" href=""> <i id="IconEye" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action </a>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td> Column3 </td>
      <td>
        <a class="btnVisible" href=""> <i id="IconEye" class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Action </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```